# Integrate $\int{9x^5\sqrt[4]{x^3+8} dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

This one I have been stuck on for awhile now, any ideas?

$\int{9x^5\sqrt[4]{x^3+8} dx}$

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?  A substitution, perhaps?

Comment: notice that if the substitution is a cubic (e.g. $x^3$ or $x^3+8$), then the derivative of the substitution is a quadratic, and $9x^5 / 3x^2$ is  cubic, which is the same degree as the substitution...is this a run-on sentence?

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** Let $u=x^3+8$. Then $du=3x^2\,dx$ and $x^3=u-8$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x^3+8=u$. Then $3x^2 dx=du$. Now then $9x^5(x^3+8)^{(1/4)}dx$ becomes

$3(u-8)u^{1/4}du$

Answer (score 0):

Substitution is probably the easiest way, but the first way that immediately "hit" me was to split the integrand up as $3x^3 \cdot (3x^2 \cdot (x^3 + 8)^{\frac 1 4})$ and integrate by parts.